# R tolower() is adding strings from previous vector element in lapply

Tags: r

I have noticed some odd behavior with R's base tolower() function when using it in lapply and I want to identify what I am doing wrong.

Here is the reproducible example:

```
  
#String
sample_string <- 
  c('Fri 12/11 Recap\n\n————————————\n\U0001f3c0UNT-WVU Total O 136✖️\n\U0001f3c0Iowa Hawkeyes 1H -7.5 \U0001f4b5\U0001f4b5\n\U0001f3c0Iowa Hawkeyes -12.5 \U0001f4b5\U0001f4b5\n————————————\n\nWhat did I say about Garza? BEAST! \n\n2-1 on the day. 10-4 in L14 overall. Lets keep this run going into the NBA regular season\n\n#GamblingTwitter', 
    '@TheNotoriousKGC https://dummyurl', 
    '\U0001f3c0Iowa Hawkeyes 1H -7.5 \U0001f4b5\U0001f4b5\n\n1 half down, 1 to go\n\nBet. Sweat. Repeat. https://dummyurl', 
    '@CxSellers \U0001f91d\U0001f91d', 
    'Fri 12/11 Picks\n\n————————————\n\U0001f3c0Iowa Hawkeyes 1H -7.5 (-110)\n\U0001f3c0Iowa Hawkeyes -12.5 (-110)\n————————————\n\nISU is 0-4-1 ATS in L5 vs Iowa. ISU 2-9 ATS on the road last yr and lost their star Tyrese Haliburton\n\nHawkeyes returning every starter and Garza is a beast\n\n#GamblingTwitte')

#Problematic behavior
lapply(1:length(sample_string), function(x) {
  sample_string[x] %>%
    tolower()
})

#Correct behavior
require(stringr)

#Problematic behavior
lapply(1:length(sample_string), function(x) {
  sample_string[x] %>%
    str_to_lower()
})
```

You will notice that in the problematic behavior example, the function is actually adding character elements that are not there. Why is that?

Comment: I get both the same `identical(out1, out2)#
[1] TRUE`

Comment: tolower is vectorized. Why are you using lapply and pipes to make it less efficient in the first place

Comment: i do not get identical() = TRUE, is this due to an OS? I am using Windows, UTF-8 encoding.